# How can I save the output and minify the html in my php files during the build tasks

Tags: php, node.js, npm, build-tools

First off please keep any tips within the scope of the question, I'm aware of Gzip etc and have it enabled, this question is not about optimisation.

This request is not about speed. I need the file/s output to be saved and minified. I am open to any approach if it results in minified files during the build but no Gulp or Grunt please as I have all the other tasks I need running with npm only.

The files in question form the html output of the site using a couple of `php_includes` for the different sections of content (hence the .php extensions).

Simply, is it possible to save the compiled output of the files (basically view source) and minify it (strip white space and comments).

Objective:

`src/index.php` >> minify, output to >> `dist/index.php`

and if possible:

`src/includes/*.php` >> minify, output to >> `dist/includes`

My attempt with npm package htmlmin is below (doesnt appear to accept .php extension)

`package.json`

```
"scripts": {

"index":"htmlmin -o dist/index.php index.php",
"includes": "htmlmin -o dist/includes/*.php includes/*.php",
"minify-html": "run-s  index includes"
}
```

Edit: Added current dependencies.

```
    "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint": "^2.10.2",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.6.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^5.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^1.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^1.3.2",
    "htmlmin": "0.0.7",
    "imagemin-cli": "^3.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.7.0",
    "onchange": "^2.4.0",
    "parallelshell": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^2.5.2",
    "stylelint": "^7.8.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^16.0.0",
    "svg-sprite-generator": "0.0.7",
    "svgo": "^0.7.1",
    "uglify-js": "^2.7.3",
    "uglifyjs-folder": "^1.1.0",
    "yargs": "^6.0.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "glob": "^7.1.1",
    "glob-html": "^0.2.5",
    "browser-sync": "^2.17.2",
    "buildify": "^0.4.0",
    "hashmark": "^4.1.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^2.1.1"
  },
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Edit: Still hoping for a solution. Something like this: http://www.binpress.com/app/phpminify/632

Full Task. `npm install`

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Test message.\"",
    "clean": "rm -f dist/{assets/css/*,assets/js/*,php/*,assets/images/*}",
    "index":"htmlmin -o dist/index.php index.php",
    "includes": "htmlmin includes/modals/* -o dist/includes/modals && htmlmin includes/content/* -o dist/includes/content",
    "minify-html": "run-s  index includes",
    "lint-js": "eslint assets/js/**/*.js || true",
    "minify-js": "uglifyjs-folder assets/js -e -o -x .js dist/assets/js",
    "concat-js": "node concat-js.js",
    "minify-images": "imagemin assets/images/* -o dist/assets/images",
    "minify-icons": "svgo -f assets/images/icons/svg -o dist/assets/images/icons/svg && svg-sprite-generate -d dist/assets/images/icons -o dist/assets/images/icons/sprite.svg",
    "compress-images": "run-s  minify-images minify-icons",
    "lint-scss": "stylelint assets/css/*.scss --syntax scss || true",
    "minify-scss": "node-sass --output-style compressed -o assets/css assets/css",
    "concat-css": "node concat-css.js",
    "concat": "run-s  concat-css && run-s  concat-js",
    "autoprefixer": "postcss -u autoprefixer -r assets/css/*.css",
    "server-sync": "browser-sync start --proxy http://diy.dev --files \"dist/*.html, dist/*.php, dist/assets/js/*.js,dist/assets/php/*.php,dist/assets/css/*.css,dist/assets/images, !node_modules/**/*.html\"",
    "build:css": "run-s lint-scss autoprefixer minify-scss concat-css",
    "build:js": "run-s lint-js concat-js minify-js",
    "build:html": "run-s minify-html",
    "build:images": "run-s minify-images minify-icons",
    "build:site": "run-s build:*",
    "watch:css": "onchange \"assets/scss\" -- run-s  build:css",
    "watch:js": "onchange \"assets/js/*.js\" -- run-s  build:js",
    "watch:html": "onchange \"*.html\" \"*.php\" -- run-s  index-lint && onchange includes/*.html -- run-s  content-lint",
    "watch:images": "onchange \"assets/images\" -- run-s  build:images",
    "watch": "run-s  serve watch:*",
    "postinstall": "run-s  build:site watch"
  },
```

Comment: There is literally zero benefit to be had by minifying PHP source code

Comment: Also, can you expand on *"Using npm only"*? Surely you'd need some sort of minification library or utility. NPM is predominantly a dependency management system

Comment: Why are you not using a Gulp build process? Chain all your build requirements into one command.

Comment: Forgot to add, npm only meant no Gulp, Grunt ect.. They are all chained, this is the last step. Added full task.

Comment: This should be done on web server level, not by trying to use a javascript package manager to minify a php file that mostly contains HTML - it's just... I don't even know where to start how bad it sounds. Nginx has a pagespeed module, I assume Apache might have something similar - have your web server do minification, they're great at doing that. Keep your code clean. You'll achieve excellent score. I'm doing that for my employer and we're getting high page speed score.

Comment: Already got the htacces template set up as well as cloudflare. I dont get it, if it was a .html file would you have a problem with it? Its just a static site, the script is run on the server to deploy the site after the repo is cloned and media folder uploaded, and it lints, minifies, concatenates, compresses and watches everything during development. Only part I haven't solved is the html(php) minification.

Comment: There's no benefit to minify PHP source code. There is however benefit in modifying the output of that PHP. Don't do it in npm. Do it in PHP.

Comment: It does NOT matter if the file is mostly HTML, you're performing including and you NEED `.php` - period. There's no discussion here any more. It's not a static HTML page, even if it only contained `<?php echo 'hello'; ?>`. Since you're so insistent, and since it's already a `.php` page, simply store the entire HTML contents in a variable and do your minification there. It's not me having a problem with the file extension, it's you who has an issue understanding how things work. This is an XY problem. Please read about it.

Comment: I clearly stated in the question it has nothing to do with speed, I've never mentioned speed. I don't understand why everyone keeps telling me to minify at the server when I clearly state in the question I have done that. All I'm trying to do is output the html in a minified form so a user can open a file and see it for themselves. No whitespace no comments. Please people, no more about speed or server side optimisation.